# Why does $this represent the current class

Tags: php

I have searched the internet for a valid explanation why `$this` when not defined represents the current class.

I have found this on the documentation when searching for `$this`:

*The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).*

I understand that to an extent, lets take this following example:

```
class Foo {
    public $Database;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Database = 'Test';
    }
        protected function Test()
    {
         return 'Example';
    }
         public function BarFunction()
    {
           return $this->Test();
    }
}

$Test = new Foo();
echo $Test->Database;
echo "\r\n\r\n";
echo $Test->BarFunction();
```

Outputs:

```
Test

Example
```

When using static functions, `self::` takes over `$this`

So my overall question, why is `$this` an automatic placeholder representative for the current class automatically without having to be defined prior to using?

and why is `self::` only to be used with static functions? Because overall, I see it neater when using

`self::ProtectedFunction();`

Over:

`$This->ProtectedFunction();`

Comment: Why?  Because that's how the language is defined.

Comment: just to annoy you, clearly...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I understand the language is defined this way, but it's always been in the back of my head why to use $this automatically?

Comment: $this is defined by PHP itself because you don't need to do it.

$this refers to a specific instance of the class and self refers to a static call to a classes methods.

Comment: who upvoted this question...

Comment: Same reason as why "A" is pronounced as "A" and written as "A".

Comment: I think it would make sense for it to be something like $_THIS to keep in tune with the naming scheme they use for reserved variables like $_GET and $_POST.  Or use a keyword (like self). Other than that, what's the big deal? :)

Comment: There is no big deal over this, I just wanted to see if there was any valid detailed response as to why it is $this, case sensitive rather than something else

Comment: PHP calls it `$this` because C++ calls it `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` refers to the current class, and `$this` refers to the current *instance* of that class.